# Mobile web - Displaying a fixed div below a relative div if the relative div is shown

Tags: jquery, html, css, iphone, mobile

I want to have a relative div at the top of the page, with `width 100%, height 50px`.
Below that div, I would like to put another one.
When the user scrolls down in the page, I want the second div to stay at the top of the window.

To achieve this, I set the first div to position:relative, and the second to `position:fixed` with `top:50px`. Then, with jQuery, I listen to scroll `$(window).on("scroll").`

**When a scroll event is fired, I set the second div's top** to `50 - $(window).scrollTop()` (with a minimum of 0), which puts the second div at the top of the window.

This works well on desktop, but on mobile (iPhone 5s Safari) the "scroll" event is fired only when the user stops scrolling, so the behavior is not the one I expect (the second div keeps its top 50px until the user stops scrolling).

Do you have any idea about how I could achieve this on mobile ?